# Google APis Explorer didn't found my available ApiMethod from my app-engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an App-Engine app that compile fine and i test the methods calls using the Google Apis Explorer on localhost (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8888/_ah/api#p/)
It works fine and i can test my api method using the Apis Explorer interface but as soon as i add a new Apimethod like

```
@ApiMethod(name = "users.insertrandomuserv4")
public User insertrandomuserv4() {
    User user = new User("234","myfirstname","mysecondname");
    return user;
}
```

and i redeploy locally my application, the Apis Explorer didn't show me the list of the different api method.
Why?
(FYI:When i remove the new method, it works again)

Edit:
Here is the rest of my class(yes I use PersistentManager and DataStoreService but it just for testing):

```
public class UserEndpoint {
@ApiMethod(name = "users.get")
public User get(@Named("key") String key) {
    //Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(User.class.getSimpleName(), key);
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    User user = pm.getObjectById(User.class, key);
    pm.close();
    return user;
}

@ApiMethod(name = "users.list")
public List<User> list() {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Query query = new Query("User");
    //query.setKeysOnly();
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
    List<Entity> ls = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(500));
    List<User> flist = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (Entity user : ls) {
        User u = new User(user);
        flist.add(u);
    }
    return flist;
}



@ApiMethod(name = "users.insert")
public User insert(User user) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Entity ent = user.toEntity();
    datastore.put(ent);
    return user;
}

@ApiMethod(name = "users.insertrandomuserv4")
public User insertrandomuserv4() {
    User user = new User("234","myfirstname","mysecondname");
    return user;
}




@ApiMethod(name = "users.getuserswithsamehometown")
public List<User> getUsersWithSameHometown(@Named("home")String home) {
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Query query = new Query("User");
    //query.addProjection(new PropertyProjection("firstname", User.class));
    query.setFilter(new Query.FilterPredicate("hometown",FilterOperator.EQUAL,home));
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
    List<Entity> ls = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(500));
    List<User> flist = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (Entity ent : ls) {
        User u = new User(ent);
        flist.add(u);
    }
    return flist;       
}


private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
    return JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional").getPersistenceManager();
}
}
```

Comment: There's most likely a path collision between your other API methods and the one you added. Can you post the entire class?

Comment: the others API methods don't have a similar name(another method's name is 'insert', I hope there is no conflict because of this...)

Comment: (I learned how to use App Engine with your Google I/O video and your slides Dan ;) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, there are path collisions going on here. From my review of your code, I believe there are two collisions: `users.get` collides with `users.getuserswithsamehometown` and `users.insert` collides with `users.insertrandomuserv4`.

The naming conventions you are using prevent collisions in the API client libraries, but not in the actual paths used to call the APIs. For example, both `.get` calls map to `GET users/{string}` and both `.insert` calls map to `POST users`.

What you should do is add a path parameter to one of the conflicting methods in each pair. For instance, `users.getuserswithsamehometown` you could update to:

```
@ApiMethod(
  name = "users.getuserswithsamehometown",
  path = "users/hometown/{home}",
  httpMethod = "GET"
)
```

This will give the method a path that no longer conflicts with your other `users.get` method. You can repeat the process for your conflicting `.insert` calls, e.g.:

```
@ApiMethod(
  name = "users.insertrandomuserv4",
  path = "users/random/",
  httpMethod = "POST"
)
```

I've added httpMethod declarations for good measure. It's generally a good idea to declare these when you start modifying other parts of the path.

Comment: It works! I confess that I didn't understood well the path parameter and its restrictions.Thanks!